# Matrix LaTeX \multirow and multicolumn

Tags: matrices

someone can help me to write this matrix.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE) showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\tempblock}[1]{%
  \boxed{%
    \begin{array}[b]{@{}ccl@{}}
    p_j^{01} & & p_j^{00}#1 \\
    & p_j^{11}\mathbf{I} & p_j^{10}#1\mathbf{e} \\
    & & p_j^{10}#1
    \end{array}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-1.2pt}% adjust this to avoid an overfull box, if necessary
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}c@{}c@{}ccc@{}}
p_j^{11} & p_j^{10} \\
p_j^{11} & & \tempblock{} \\
& & & \ddots \\
p_j^{11} & & & & \tempblock{} \\
p_j^{11} & & & & & \tempblock{t} \\
& p_j^{00} & & & & & p_j^{01} \\
& p_j^{00}\mathbf{e} & & & & & & p_j^{11}\mathbf{I} \\
p_j^{11} & p_j^{00}
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want that the items in the first column are centered with respect to the boxes, then remove `[b]` in the code for `\tempblock`.